# The Lucky Number Seven... or is it?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

While biking with your friend, you come to a fork in the road. You wonder why there's a fork in the road here, you don't remember seeing it before. Your friend and you decide to split up; you'll go left, he'll go right.

You keep biking. Time flies and you don't realize how dark it is. You seem lost. You see a glimpse of light coming from a house up a head. After you knock, you don't get an answer, so you decide to walk in the room. The door shuts closed behind you.

You frantically try to re-open the door, but it won't work. You see a lock pad telling you to input a 1-digit code. You see the cipher below:

```
7/7-7777/7777-777/7777-7/77-77/7777-777/7-7777/77777-777/7  77777/7777-7777/7777-7777/777-77/7 777/7-7/77-7777/77-77777/77777-7/777-77/7777-777/7
```

You feel sure that the answer must be `7`, but you don't want to take any chances, since you see that you only have one chance to enter a number into the lock pad.

You solve the cipher with a piece of paper, enter a number into the lock pad, and walk right out. What number did you enter?

Hint 1:

> The use of the number `7` will be used in **almost** all the steps in solving the cipher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *almost* have it, I think. First:

> Interpret each group of slash-separated sevens as a letter in [tap code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code).  So 7/7 = 11 = A, 7777/7777 = 44 = T, etc. This produces the string:
>
> atobilul ytsf lbrzcil

Then:

> Decode this string as a [rail fence cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher) with 7 levels. This produces the string:
>
> aol sbirfyubtilt zlcl

Finally:

> Decode this as if it had been encoded with ROT-7. This produces the string:
>
> the lubkyrnumbem seve
>
> So I assume the answer should read "**THE LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN**" but perhaps I missed or messed up a step along the way. Or have I fallen for a really good red herring and, as the title suggests, this isn't actually the answer?